# Delete rows from table (deleting more rows than those which are selected)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, underscore.js, ag-grid

I have a table with following details.

```
Row_no | Contact Person | Address |
 26    |  Andarw        | DEL     |
 25    |  Celret        | DRT     |
 24    |  Driok         | ddd     |
 23    |  Andarw        | DEL     |
 22    |  Celret        | DRT     |
 2     |  Driok         | ddd     |
 3     |  Andarw        | DEL     |
 4     |  Celret        | DRT     |
 5     |  Driok         | ddd     |
```

Row_no is unique. I have kept it as unique so that while deleting rows, i would come to know which rows i want to delete. But the problem is as follows.

If i delete rows with Row_no 25,24,23,22 - it is deleting these rows but it is also deleting 2,3,4,5. It is behaving weird.

Here is the code i use...

```
function remove(names) {
    currentrows = currentrows.filter(function (obj) {
        return names.indexOf(obj.row_no) == -1;
    });
}



 $scope.deleteuser = function () {

        //selectedRowsString is a string. its value is '25,24,23,22'
        remove(selectedRowsString);
        $scope.gridOptions.rowData = currentrows; //updates new rowdata to grid table
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData($scope.gridOptions.rowData);//updates new rowdata to grid table
        selectedRows = "";//this is to reset for next deletion
        selectedRowsString = ""; //this is to reset for next deletion

};
```

I believe the indexOf in function remove(names) is causing the problem. While deleting row_no 22,23,24,25-- it is also deleting 2,3,4,5 because 22,23,24,25 has those values in the index.

I am not getting exactly how to correct this error. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put a fiddle together for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/czeee3dd/

Firstly, you are correct about your problem. As you are doing an `indexOf` on a string, any occurrence of the `row_no` in the string is going to be picked up.

An easy fix is to firstly convert your names string into an array of strings.

```
names = names.split(',');
```

Then you can do the comparison you currently have, but you have to make sure you convert each row_no value to a string before comparing.

```
return names.indexOf(item.row_no.toString()) == -1;
```

Full fiddle code here:

```
var data = [
  {row_no: 26, name: 'Andarw'},
  {row_no: 21, name: 'another'},
  {row_no: 2, name: 'thid'},
  {row_no: 4, name: 'hagrid'}
];

function doFilter(names){
  names = names.split(',');
  var filtered = data.filter(function(item){
      return names.indexOf(item.row_no.toString()) == -1;
  });
  return filtered;
}

var output = doFilter('26,21');
console.log(output);
```